# In a Jinja template file, how to load a bash script for the startup-script of an instance

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-platform, jinja2, google-deployment-manager

We have a template `container_instance_template.jinja` which define our instance properties for our Deployment Manager of GCP.

For the `startup-script` metatag we have a `_startup-script.sh` the file we would like to load. But we keep getting template load error.

Our template:

```
resources:
- name: {{ IT_NAME }}
  type: compute.v1.instanceTemplate
  properties:
    properties:
      metadata:
        items:
        - key: gce-container-declaration
          value: |
            {{ GenerateManifest(env['name'], properties['port'],properties['dockerImage'], properties['dockerEnv'])|indent(12) }}
        - key: startup-script
          value: ????????????
```

We've tried everything:

```
 key: startup-script
 value: |
  {{ properties['startupScript'] }}

# This one does not work, because as it's just the reference to the file, GCP doesn't pick up the contents and doesn't execute the script. As far as we understood, it should though, anyways.
```

```
key: startup-script
 value: |
  {% include properties['startupScript'] %}

# This one does not work, because we get the error TemplateNotFound: ./_startup-script.sh
```

This is the error we get:

```
- code: MANIFEST_EXPANSION_USER_ERROR
  location: /deployments/app/manifests/manifest-14723924
  message: |-
    Manifest expansion encountered the following errors: Exception in container_instance_template.jinja
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        return template.render(resource)
        return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "<template>", line 22, in top-level template code
        raise TemplateNotFound(template)
    TemplateNotFound: ./_startup-script.sh
     Resource: container_instance_template.jinja Resource: config
```

In our last attempt we were trying to create a Python function and import it to the template, but no success:

```
# container_instance_template.jinja
imports:
- path: helpers.py 
- path: properties['startupScript']

# And then using:

{{ include_file(properties['startupScript']) }}


# helpers.py

import jinja2

def include_file(name):
    return jinja2.Markup(loader.get_source(env, name)[0])

loader = jinja2.PackageLoader(__name__, 'templates')
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)
env.globals['include_file'] = include_file
```

We can't find any GCP examples, guide, documentation or anything else. If we inline the bash script it works, but then it's a hacky solution.

We tried all types of reference to the file. It's there, other files work normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the metadata tag "startup-script" to "startup-script-url" and linking to a google cloud storage location? Something like:

```
resources:
- name: {{ IT_NAME }}
  type: compute.v1.instanceTemplate
  properties:
    properties:
      metadata:
        items:
        - key: gce-container-declaration
          value: |
            {{ GenerateManifest(env['name'], properties['port'],properties['dockerImage'], properties['dockerEnv'])|indent(12) }}
        - key: startup-script-url
          value: gs:project/bucket/yourscript.sh
```

Make sure you give the appropriate permission to the VM to access the google cloud storage bucket.

Check out [this google article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_a_startup_script) for more details on other ways to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding startup script into the yaml file rather jinja like below:
imports:

```
- path: instance.jinja
- path: ../startup-script.sh
  name: startup-script.sh

resources:
- name: my-instance
  type: instance.jinja
  properties:
    metadata-from-file:
      startup-script: startup-script.sh
    zone: ZONE_TO_RUN
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the git repo from google found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/examples/v2/vm_startup_script/jinja/vm_template.jinja). This annoying thing cost me like two hours to figure out. The correct example can be found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/examples/v2/metadata_from_file/jinja/instance.jinja):

```
metadata:
  items:
  {% for key, value in properties['metadata-from-file'].iteritems() %}
  - key: {{ key }}
    value: |
      {{ imports[value]|indent(10) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Be sure to put the following in your config.yaml file:

```
imports:
- path: instance.jinja
- path: ../startup-script.sh
  name: startup-script.sh

resources:
- name: my-instance
  type: instance.jinja
  properties:
    metadata-from-file:
      startup-script: startup-script.sh
    zone: ZONE_TO_RUN
```